# Getting the max id in mysql using java

Tags: java, mysql, max

I just want to ask on how to get the maximum number of an VARCHAR ID for example;

```
ID
2014-00001
2014-00002
2014-00006
2014-00003
```

how to get max of this column?

and one more thing I also want to know what about

```
HS-01
HS-02
HS-09
HS-03
```

how to get max of this column?

Comment: what does it mean "max" - give examples from the example data...

Comment: In a production environment, actually in any environment, it might be more wise to calculate these things in MySQL directly, rather than sending all output data over the network, while you are only interest in the "max".

Answer (score 0):

Not in JAVA, but in mysql directly. Something like this might work

```
SELECT MAX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ID,'-',-1) + 0) ...
```

Explanation:
substring_index selects the string right from the first occurance of the delimiter '-'. Then you add 0 to cast the string to integer. Then you choose the max value.

It's not tested, so you might have to tweak a little.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. It will get the characters after 2014- , then cast them as an int, then get the highest one. For HS-01, change `(ID, 6)` for `(ID, 4)`

```
select
    max(cast(substring(ID, 6) as UNSIGNED)) as maxid
from
    table
```

Casting : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast
Subtring: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring